# WooCommerce "Show Cart" button in class="woocommerce-message" uses http instead of https

Tags: wordpress, http, https, woocommerce

I use wordpress and woocommerce for my online shop. The complete shop has https using a ssl certificate. Only one single link is still getting http instead of https. After adding something to the cart the message appears that something has been successfully added to cart.
It has the class `class="woocommerce-message"`
 And in this message the link "Show Cart" is http only. I can't find where this link is created to change it to https. Does somebody know where to change http to https for this specific link?

```
<div class="woocommerce-message"><a href="http://www.art-wood.de/warenkorb/" class="button wc-forward">Warenkorb anzeigen</a> &bdquo;Visitenkartenetui »Akemi«&ldquo; wurde deinem Warenkorb hinzugefügt.</div>
```

[image]

Things mentioned below I have checked long time ago.

> There are these 3 things to check:
>
> 1. change HTTP to https in permalink settings from WordPress dashboard settings. *-> Yes I did that and its working for the whole rest of the site.*
> 2. on woocommerce plugin>> settings >> check out>> there would be an option for https checkout. *-> This is enabled a loooong time ago ;)*
> 3. last thing to check if the product involved in add to cart has media image or any link which is HTTP instead of https. *-> I replaced http with https to all media files via the data base.*

Answer (score 1):

It could be a caching issue you must be facing, try to duplicate the same problem after clearing browser cache. I am assuming you have SSL certificate applied on your domain.

There are these 3 things to check:

1. change HTTP to https in permalink settings from WordPress dashboard settings.
2. on woo commerce plugin>> settings >> check out>> there would be an option for https checkout.
3. last thing to check if the product involved in add to cart has media image or any link which is HTTP instead of https.

If you could share the theme and plugins you are using on your WordPress installation, it could help to understand the problem

**Edited**----

I have checked in my woo commerce installation and PHP code of the woo commerce plugin. I do not have any third party plugin and that is why I was having secured link in "View Cart".

I suggest you to simply look into the woocart pro plugin that if you are providing any custom link to show basket on your website.

As there is href in that div="woocommerce message" element. you have to change the view basket link from http to https.

The only place you have to look is your third party plugin you are using for showing custom cart.

Comment: Hi Adit Goel,
thank you for your hints! I did check all the things you are talking about long time before. The whole website uses https except this special link. Even the "To Cart" link in the plugin woocart pro has the https encryption.

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution by myself. Maybe its helpful for someone having a similar problem. So here is what I did.

I have replaced all http://www.domain strings (?) with https://www.domain using this code in the phpmyadmin panel.

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.oldurl', 'http://www.newurl');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.oldurl','http://www.newurl');
```

Now the link in the "Show Cart" message has https.